# How make animated search?

Tags: jquery

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcsHA.jpg)
I'm trying to do a search that opens by clicking on the icon.
Mobile version works open-close, but for Desktop need change code.

I have this code, but can't change correct. I try delete block mediaCheck, but it is not help.
Instead of a minus correct the question or help, please, with any advice.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    "matchMedia",
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, mediaCheck) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Check wether the incoming string is not empty or if doesn't consist of spaces.
     *
     * @param {String} value - Value to check.
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    function isEmpty(value) {
        return (value.length === 0) || (value == null) || /^\s+$/.test(value);
    }

    $.widget('mage.quickSearch', {
        options: {
            autocomplete: 'off',
            minSearchLength: 2,
            responseFieldElements: 'ul li',
            selectClass: 'selected',
            template:
                '<li class="<%- data.row_class %>" id="qs-option-<%- data.index %>" role="option">' +
                    '<span class="qs-option-name">' +
                       ' <%- data.title %>' +
                    '</span>' +
                    '<span aria-hidden="true" class="amount">' +
                        '<%- data.num_results %>' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</li>',
            submitBtn: 'button[type="submit"]',
            searchLabel: '[data-role=minisearch-label]',
            isExpandable: null
        },

        _create: function () {
            this.responseList = {
                indexList: null,
                selected: null
            };
            this.autoComplete = $(this.options.destinationSelector);
            this.searchForm = $(this.options.formSelector);
            this.submitBtn = this.searchForm.find(this.options.submitBtn)[0];
            this.searchLabel = $(this.options.searchLabel);
            this.isExpandable = this.options.isExpandable;

            _.bindAll(this, '_onKeyDown', '_onPropertyChange', '_onSubmit');

            this.submitBtn.disabled = true;

            this.element.attr('autocomplete', this.options.autocomplete);

            mediaCheck({
                media: '(max-width: 768px)',
                entry: function () {
                    this.isExpandable = true;
                }.bind(this),
                exit: function () {
                    this.isExpandable = false;
                    this.element.removeAttr('aria-expanded');
                }.bind(this)
            });

            this.searchLabel.on('click', function (e) {
                // allow input to lose its' focus when clicking on label
                if (this.isExpandable && this.isActive()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }.bind(this));

            this.element.on('blur', $.proxy(function () {

                setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                    if (this.autoComplete.is(':hidden')) {
                        this.setActiveState(false);
                    }
                    this.autoComplete.hide();
                    this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
                }, this), 250);
            }, this));

            this.element.trigger('blur');

            this.element.on('focus', this.setActiveState.bind(this, true));
            this.element.on('keydown', this._onKeyDown);
            this.element.on('input propertychange', this._onPropertyChange);

            this.searchForm.on('submit', $.proxy(function() {
                this._onSubmit();
                this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         * Checks if search field is active.
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        isActive: function () {
            return this.searchLabel.hasClass('active');
        },

        /**
         * Sets state of the search field to provided value.
         *
         * @param {Boolean} isActive
         */
        setActiveState: function (isActive) {
            this.searchLabel.toggleClass('active', isActive);

            if (this.isExpandable) {
                this.element.attr('aria-expanded', isActive);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @private
         * @return {Element} The first element in the suggestion list.
         */
        _getFirstVisibleElement: function () {
            return this.responseList.indexList ? this.responseList.indexList.first() : false;
        },

        /**
         * @private
         * @return {Element} The last element in the suggestion list.
         */
        _getLastElement: function () {
            return this.responseList.indexList ? this.responseList.indexList.last() : false;
        },

        /**
         * @private
         * @param {Boolean} show Set attribute aria-haspopup to "true/false" for element.
         */
        _updateAriaHasPopup: function(show) {
            if (show) {
                this.element.attr('aria-haspopup', 'true');
            } else {
                this.element.attr('aria-haspopup', 'false');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Clears the item selected from the suggestion list and resets the suggestion list.
         * @private
         * @param {Boolean} all - Controls whether to clear the suggestion list.
         */
        _resetResponseList: function (all) {
            this.responseList.selected = null;

            if (all === true) {
                this.responseList.indexList = null;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Executes when the search box is submitted. Sets the search input field to the
         * value of the selected item.
         * @private
         * @param {Event} e - The submit event
         */
        _onSubmit: function (e) {
            var value = this.element.val();

            if (isEmpty(value)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            if (this.responseList.selected) {
                this.element.val(this.responseList.selected.find('.qs-option-name').text());
            }
        },

        /**
         * Executes when keys are pressed in the search input field. Performs specific actions
         * depending on which keys are pressed.
         * @private
         * @param {Event} e - The key down event
         * @return {Boolean} Default return type for any unhandled keys
         */
        _onKeyDown: function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case $.ui.keyCode.HOME:
                    this._getFirstVisibleElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                    this.responseList.selected = this._getFirstVisibleElement();
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.END:
                    this._getLastElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                    this.responseList.selected = this._getLastElement();
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE:
                    this._resetResponseList(true);
                    this.autoComplete.hide();
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.ENTER:
                    this.searchForm.trigger('submit');
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.DOWN:
                    if (this.responseList.indexList) {
                        if (!this.responseList.selected) {
                            this._getFirstVisibleElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = this._getFirstVisibleElement();
                        }
                        else if (!this._getLastElement().hasClass(this.options.selectClass)) {
                            this.responseList.selected = this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass).next().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                        } else {
                            this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this._getFirstVisibleElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = this._getFirstVisibleElement();
                        }
                        this.element.val(this.responseList.selected.find('.qs-option-name').text());
                        this.element.attr('aria-activedescendant', this.responseList.selected.attr('id'));
                    }
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.UP:
                    if (this.responseList.indexList !== null) {
                        if (!this._getFirstVisibleElement().hasClass(this.options.selectClass)) {
                            this.responseList.selected = this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass).prev().addClass(this.options.selectClass);

                        } else {
                            this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this._getLastElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = this._getLastElement();
                        }
                        this.element.val(this.responseList.selected.find('.qs-option-name').text());
                        this.element.attr('aria-activedescendant', this.responseList.selected.attr('id'));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Executes when the value of the search input field changes. Executes a GET request
         * to populate a suggestion list based on entered text. Handles click (select), hover,
         * and mouseout events on the populated suggestion list dropdown.
         * @private
         */
        _onPropertyChange: function () {
            var searchField = this.element,
                clonePosition = {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    // Removed to fix display issues
                    // left: searchField.offset().left,
                    // top: searchField.offset().top + searchField.outerHeight(),
                    width: searchField.outerWidth()
                },
                source = this.options.template,
                template = mageTemplate(source),
                dropdown = $('<ul role="listbox"></ul>'),
                value = this.element.val();

            this.submitBtn.disabled = isEmpty(value);

            if (value.length >= parseInt(this.options.minSearchLength, 10)) {
                $.get(this.options.url, {q: value}, $.proxy(function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                        element.index = index;
                        var html = template({
                            data: element
                        });
                        dropdown.append(html);
                    });
                    this.responseList.indexList = this.autoComplete.html(dropdown)
                        .css(clonePosition)
                        .show()
                        .find(this.options.responseFieldElements + ':visible');

                    this._resetResponseList(false);
                    this.element.removeAttr('aria-activedescendant');

                    if (this.responseList.indexList.length) {
                        this._updateAriaHasPopup(true);
                    } else {
                        this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
                    }

                    this.responseList.indexList
                        .on('click', function (e) {
                            this.responseList.selected = $(e.currentTarget);
                            this.searchForm.trigger('submit');
                        }.bind(this))
                        .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
                            this.responseList.indexList.removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            $(e.target).addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = $(e.target);
                            this.element.attr('aria-activedescendant', $(e.target).attr('id'));
                        }.bind(this))
                        .on('mouseout', function (e) {
                            if (!this._getLastElement() && this._getLastElement().hasClass(this.options.selectClass)) {
                                $(e.target).removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                                this._resetResponseList(false);
                            }
                        }.bind(this));
                }, this));
            } else {
                this._resetResponseList(true);
                this.autoComplete.hide();
                this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
                this.element.removeAttr('aria-activedescendant');
            }
        }
    });

    return $.mage.quickSearch;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

wow that's a lot of code. in the future add ONLY RELEVANT code and try to make working examples of your problems . Do NOT link to external sites

That being said, here is an example of what ( i think ) you are trying to achieve . I made the snippet below

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".search").toggleClass("opened")
})
```

```css
.form {
 position:relative;
 width:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 
}
.search {
 transform:scaleX(0);
 transform-origin:right;
 transition:0.3s;
}
.search.opened {
 transform:scale(1);
}
.button {
 position:absolute;right:0;top:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
<input type="search" class="search">
<a class="button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

the above code  can be modified to suit your purpose

Comment: Yep, thank you! I delete link. But I tried this option before asking a question. The problem is that the original search behavior code conflicts with any overlay. This led me to the conclusion that I need changes inside the code. Also, the wrong way to add code over the top is because this causes the search to flicker during the page load time.